# How to call windows api (FindWindow) in an apache cgi application?

Tags: windows, apache, winapi, cgi

I have a native compiled cgi application running through Apache under Windows. The app works fine. Tested in windows 7, windows 8, windows server 2003.

I'm trying to get a windows handle through [FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) winapi but the return is always 0.

Calling FindWindow with the same arguments in a console application works fine (returns the correct window handle)

Is there any specificity of Apache cgi processes that prevents FindWindow works?

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Is the process running in a service?

Comment: No. It is a standalone application. A process is created each time a request is done to apache.
But Apache is running as a service

Comment: And is the window you search for in session 0?

Comment: No. The window is a desktop app

I think that the problem is that apache creates the cgi process and since apache is running as a service the function does not returns windows from desktop as explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340122/findwindow-fails-from-service-application

Your tip was valuable to find the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window is in an interactive desktop. The CGI process is invoked from the Apache service and runs in a non-interactive desktop in session 0. Hence the call to `FindWindow` is not able to see the target window.